# View optional mission objectives during a mission?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Most missions in GTA5 have optional mission objectives. Completing them or not determines what medal you receive at the end of the mission (gold, silver, bronze).

So far I have found it quite frustrating to complete a mission only to be told that I didn't get gold because I didn't "headshot 10 bikers" or because I "wrecked my vehicle".

Is it possible to view the optional objectives during a mission? I've had a quick look around on the in-game menus, but haven't found anything so far.

Comment: The only way I know of, would be to look at the "Replay" list in the "Game" menu, but it won't help because "Replay is not available during missions" :(

Comment: I have not found a way.  My guess is Rockstar is encouraging players to play missions multiple times.

Comment: My best guess is that you would have to look them up individually online somewhere, which is a huge pain.

Comment: I suspected as much. Shame really, but I suppose it does make me play through the mission once without worrying about a thing and just having fun. In the Assassin Creed series, the optional objectives make you complete a mission in a certain way and it actually makes it fairly tedious after a while. Not to mention I restart the mission every time I fail one :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no way to do it in-game, currently. However, you can look up WIKI's online that describe mission objectives. See [Missions in GTA V](http://gta.wikia.com/Missions_in_GTA_V) or [GTA 5 Wiki Guide](http://www.ign.com/wikis/gta-5). Hope that helps!

Comment: Or you can view it in MISSION section ( next to CHECKLIST ) in Social Club online in computer.